# What is the most efficient way to remove a space from a string when importing a csv file to SQL Server using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I will be importing records from thousands of CSV files using SSIS.  These CSV files will contain a Postal Code column, which has the format A5A 5A5, where "A" is any letter and "5" is any number from 0 to 9.

There is a space between the "A5A" and "5A5" that I want to remove, so that all Postal Codes appear as "A5A5A5".

I am reviewing the documentation and see several options, and I'm trying to narrow down the best one, i.e. the one that requires the least number of steps.  So far I am looking at the [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) transformation, but that would involve adding another column to my SQL Table.

Is there a way I can trim the space without having to add an extra column?

Comment: A derived column can replace *or* add a column to a dataset in the dataflow, and even if it added a new one that doesn't mandate you have to add a column to your destination; you don't have to map every column in the source of destination just those you need. A derived column is exactly what you want here.

Comment: From the documentation *you* linked in the **Options** section: *"**Derived Column:** Select a derived column from the list. Choose whether to add the derived column as a new output column, or to replace the data in an existing column."*

Comment: Are all problematic postal codes in the format "A5A 5A5"? Could that pattern appear in other columns? (I would imagine not). Is the OS windows or *nix/mac?

Comment: Are all the csv files being loaded to the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETL is an alternate option. Bulk load the data into a staging table. Then do a simple select into the destination to do the transformation. I might be tempted to not use SSIS.  BCP or Import-DbaCsv (DBATools powershell module) would both be a quick alternates. If you know PowerShell and want to process the files in a pipe, you can pipe the files into Import-DbaCsv. The PowerShell script can also execute Invoke-DbaQuery to run update or insert queries to do the transformation.

SSIS can also just do the bulk load and then run the T-SQL to do the transformations. I don't like the overhead of maintaining and upgrading SSIS packages. I'd take T-SQL jobs over SSIS jobs any day.  (We have about 1/2 year for a FTE to upgrade our SSIS packages to SQL 2019. The T-SQL jobs just keep working when moved to a new version.)

Or go the ETL route and do the transformation in the SSIS data flow. A Derived Column transformation between a flat file source and a OLE DB destination should do the trick.

[image]

To handle multiple files, you can use the Foreach Loop Container.  There's an enumerator for files using a wildcard path. (The initial T-SQL task just truncates the table for testing.)

[image]

You'll need to parameterize the thing to get the file source to be each file.

For PowerShell it might be something like (no transformation yet) the script below.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\TestFolder\*.csv' | 
    import-dbacsv -SqlInstance 'localhost\DEV' -Database 'Test' -Schema 'dbo' -Table 'Test' -AutoCreateTable -verbose
```

If you run this in the ISE, be aware of a bug where the connection might not be released after calling import-dbacsv that will cause it to hang.  This is not an issue in the command line from what I can tell. (If this happens to you, you might have to kill the ISE process - closing it is not enough.)

Comment: @DalhousieDuck Perhaps mark it as an answer?  (Blatant trolling for points.)

Answer (score 4):

As @Larnu answers via comments, a Derived Column is likely the most appropriate component to use here.

The expression you're looking for is a [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replace-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15). Syntax ought to be

```
REPLACE([PostalCode], " ", "")
```

You have 10 columns from your CSV. The Derived Column can either replace and existing or add a new column to row buffer. I would advocate adding a new column. `PostalCodeStripped` or something like that. At some point, something weird is going to happen with the data and you'll get an `A5A 5A5` that didn't get the space stripped. Having both the original and the parsed value available in debugging can help sort out problems (Oh, this has a non-breaking space or a tab instead of a space, or in addition to)

*But*, just because a column is in the buffer does not mean you need to create a column for that in the destination table. Just unmap the `PostalCode` from the row buffer and map `PostalCodeStripped` to the `PostalCode` column in the database. You'll see what I'm talking about in the destination component. By default, they'll map based on name matching but you're welcome to wire them up however you see fit.